# Rename refactoring in VS Code

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio-code

In visual studio we can use Resharper  for refactoring, but in VS Code I can't find a good refactoring tool.I just want to know if there is any name refactoring tool in VS code especially for type script?

Answer (score 3):

The official way to refactor variable names is **F2** key.
It's able to change variable names in the other files too.

[image]

You can find out more about the default refactoring in VS Code here: [Refactoring source code in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring)

Comment: Yeah it works only in ts files, but it doesn't apply to templates in angular.

Comment: It's true. There aren't any extension which knows this.
A solution: right-click to the variable in the template and choose 'Peek Reference', then rename symbol and change name in the template.

Comment: I am wondering how come this basic thing never got implemented in VS Code.